# Is there a way to detect when the user has changed the clock time manually from the settings on their device?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am stuck up with the two actions in the broadcast receiver.
1) ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
2) ACTION_TIME_TICK

Is there any way of determining the fact that the time is changed by the user manually from the device settings and not by the system automatically?

These broadcasts somehow are triggered for automatically as well which I am not looking forth.

Can anyone provide me with any suggestions for the same?

I was looking at the following SO question, but can there be any possible alternative for the same?

[Android: is there any additional information from Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756493/android-is-there-any-additional-information-from-intent-action-time-changed)

Comment: save values in shared prefrence time to change will store .

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912885/action-time-changed-or-action-date-changed-cant-make-them-work

Comment: can you please elaborate his question programmatic......some codes post with question