# Get Amount of Time change Using Android Broadcast

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Its simple Question

**I am want to get the Amount of Time change By User using system setting**

I am  using Broadcast Receiver,from below broadcast Receiver , I only get the notice that  time has changed 
But how much Changed I don't no .

I want to get the whether the user incremented the time or decremented

And How much Incremented or Decremented ?

is it Possible to get this ?

if yes   then how ?

**Note : The IntentExtra didnt have any Extra information**

```
<receiver android:name=".Receivers.TimeChangeReceivers">

            <intent-filter >

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

My Class

```
public class TimeChangeReceivers extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String TAG= TimeChangeReceivers.class.getSimpleName ();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e ( TAG," Time Change!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is any data that you can get, it will be stored in intent extras. Try to get `intent.getExtras()`, it will give you `Bundle`, and then you can get values from it.

When you get your `Bundle` try `bundle.keySet()` to get all keys from it, and look for needed info.

Comment: intent.getExtras() give null

Comment: Try to run with debuger  and inspect variable. I think you'll find something there. It can be just `intent.getString()` or so on.

Comment: I run it , but nothing there

Comment: @kamran look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756493/android-is-there-any-additional-information-from-intent-action-time-changed